# Different ways of loading libraries in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

What is the difference of loading a library in CodeIgniter via,

1. autoload.php
2. Controller class

Is there any point in loading the library in the constructor method of the controller class as,

```
$this->load->library(array('form_validation'));
```

when I can just load them at the autoload.php?

Thank you!

Comment: Personally I hate the way CI loads classes, it's how should I put it, to old school.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I am a newbie to CodeIgniter as well as MVC architecture. So I don't yet have a sufficient knowledge to have an opinion against how CI loads classes :) Perhaps you could suggest me some better alternatives?

Comment: I still have CI2, but my opinion is based on the fact that loading classes using the CI way, makes your code tightly bound to CI, instead of loading them the "normal" way ( with an autoloader ).  Basically you wind up with all these dependencies on CI when you load them using their loader class.

Comment: I only use CI for Emailing,  Routing, and their Input class, Even those last two I had to modify, ( core/My_Router etc.. ) ... lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not loading all libraries in autoload is simply for performance reasons.
If you rarely use a certain library, you might want to load it only when using it's relevant controller. Autoloading every library all the time could be "wasteful".

Comment: if they use a PSR autoloader, the files are only loaded when creating a new instance of the class.   I use my own custom  PSR autoloader for CI2.  The only reason I use CI is that, is what the previous developer used.  If I redo our application at work I will use my own framework :)